# Python Error:Unindent does not match any outer uindentation limit

Tags: python, indentation

As you can see I am a novice in Programming and started with Python, the above said error is occurring on the highlighted line of code. 
How to ride over this...

```
import random

secret= random.randint (1,100)
guess=0
tries=0

print "AHOY! I am the dead pirate Roberts, and I ahve a secret!"
print  "It is a number from 1 to 99. I will give you six tries."

while guess  !=secret and tries <6:
    guess= input("what's yer guess? " )
    if  guess < secret :
                 print "Too Low, ye curvy dog!"
    elif guess > secret:
                 print "Too high, landlubber!"
                 tries= tries +1

         ***if  guess == secret  :***
             print "Avast! Ye got it! found my secret, ye did!"
                 else:
             print "No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!"
             print "The secret number was ", secret"
```

Answer (score 2):

Python uses indentation to denote code blocks. The indentation of your code is not valid (the indentation of the `if` in question doesn't line up with any previous block; from a quick look over the code, there's at least one more error).

The following is a short clear explanation of how indentation works in Python: http://diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html

Answer (score 0):

In python, you must keep a constant indentation between your blocks.

And in the `if guess < secret:` code block, the indentation is much longer than in the while code block.

The proper code is :

```
while guess  !=secret and tries <6:
    guess= input("what's yer guess? " )
    if  guess < secret :
        print "Too Low, ye curvy dog!"
    elif guess > secret:
        print "Too high, landlubber!"
        tries= tries +1

    if  guess == secret  :
        print "Avast! Ye got it! found my secret, ye did!"
    else:
        print "No more guesses! Better luck next time, matey!"
        print "The secret number was ", secret"
```